# nginx rewrite WITHOUT change url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to use rewrite function in my nginx server.

When I try "http://www.example.com/1234", I want to rewrite "http://www.example.com/v.php?id=1234" and want to get "http://www.example.com/1234" in browser.

Here is nginx.conf file

```
...
  location ~ /[0-9]+ {
      rewrite "/([0-9]+)" http://www.example.com/v.php?id=$1 break;
  }
...
```

When I try "http://www.example.com/1234"

I want to ...

```
url bar in browser : http://www.example.com/1234
real url : http://www.example.com/v.php?id=1234
```

but I'm in trouble ...

```
url bar in browser : http://www.example.com/v.php?id=1234
real url : http://www.example.com/v.php?id=1234
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Reference: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite

> If the replacement string begins with http:// then the client will be redirected, and any further >rewrite directives are terminated.

So remove the http:// part and it should work:

```
location ~ /[0-9]+ {
        rewrite "/([0-9]+)" /v.php?id=$1 break;
}
```

Comment: I needed to use 'last' flag instead of 'break' as the rewritten url is handled by a different location.

Comment: what if i want to proxy_pass to service in another port using `rewrite`?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I needed to use 'last' to make it work due I had other rules that I wanted to be applied:

```
location ~ /[0-9]+ {
    rewrite "/([0-9]+)" /v.php?id=$1 last;
}
```