# Nginx URL rewrite changes URL

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I need to redirect a URL in nginx. My rule looks like this which actually causes the browser to visibly change the URL, which is not what is expected.

```
   location / {
      rewrite ^/dentists/bangalore/indiranagar/$ http://abc.com/doctorsInArea.htm?cID=bangalore&aID=indiranagar break;
    }
```

I read another question here [nginx rewrite WITHOUT change url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322826/nginx-rewrite-without-change-url) which tells me to remove the http part . I tried

```
    location / {
      rewrite ^/dentists/bangalore/indiranagar/$ /doctorsInArea.htm?cID=bangalore&aID=indiranagar break;
    }
```

This one throws a 404 even though http://abc.com/doctorsInArea.htm?cID=bangalore&aID=indiranagar works fine when hit from the browser. Any insights on the problem would be apprreciated.

Comment: I would try
    location / {
      rewrite ^/dentists/bangalore/indiranagar/$ http://abc.com/doctorsInArea.htm?cID=bangalore&aID=indiranagar last;
    }

Comment: It just renders an empty page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using the following.

```
location / {
      rewrite "/dentists/bangalore/indiranagar/" /doctorsInArea.htm?cID=bangalore&aID=indiranagar last;
    }
```

Thanks!