# How in Nginx to do rewrite without changing URL in address bar

Tags: nginx

I've been trying to do rewrite in Nginx:
domain.com/one/two -> onetwo.domain.com. The URL that user sees should not be changed in address bar.

This code does not work correctly - it changes URL in address bar

```
rewrite ^/one/two/ http://onetwo.domain.com/ last;
```

What solution must be there?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nginx rewrite WITHOUT change url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322826/nginx-rewrite-without-change-url)

Comment: @rickyA Definitely not a duplicate of that. This one can't be done.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible, because you're changing hostnames. Browser security is tied to it, as is webserver configuration.

You can rewrite URLs within same hostname, but changing hostnames requires redirect or using a frame.

Answer (score 4):

Use proxy pass:

```
location /one/two/ { 
    proxy_pass http://onetwo.domain.com/;
    include proxy.conf;
}
```

Where proxy.conf is where you keep your proxy settings, stuff like:

```
proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_connect_timeout     120;
proxy_send_timeout        900;
proxy_read_timeout        900;
proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        REQUEST_SCHEME  $scheme;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Ssl         on;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol    $scheme;
proxy_set_header        X-scheme        $scheme;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
proxy_set_header        'SERVER_PORT'   $server_port;
```